# One field depends on another using java script and thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a spring boot application with thymleaf at the frontend. I have a requirement to make one text box as mandetory (or required) if some other drop down is selected. I know that we can't do this with thymleaf as it is server side technology.
The form is as follows

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div th:replace="navigation :: nav_bar"></div>
    <div class="col">
        <form th:object="${answeredQuestionnaire}" method="post">
            <h1>[[#{nav.bcmDecisionCriteria}]]</h1>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div th:each="role: ${loggedInUser.applicationUserRoles}">
                <div class="form-row">
                    
                        <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-4  text-left pt-2">
                                    <label class="form-group font-weight-bold"> [[#{review.differentBCMClass}]] :</label>
                                </div>
                                <div  class="form-group col-2  text-left pt-2">
                                    <select th:field="*{classOverridden}" name="classOverridden">
                                        <option value=""  default >[[#{pleaseSelect}]]</option>
                                        <option class="text-center" th:value="1"  >1</option>
                                        <option class="text-center" th:value="2"   >2</option>
                                        <option class="text-center" th:value="3"   >3</option>
                                        <option class="text-center" th:value="4" >4</option>
                                        <option class="text-center" th:value="0" >0</option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-6 ">
                        <label class="font-weight-bold "> [[#{review.commentForDifferentClass}]] : </label>
                        <textarea rows="5"
                                  th:placeholder="#{comment}"
                                  th:field="*{classOverriddenComment}"
                                  th:value="${answeredQuestionnaire.classOverriddenComment}"
                                  th:text="${answeredQuestionnaire.classOverriddenComment}"
                                  class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                


                
                <br>
                <div class="form-group form-row text-center"
                     th:if="${role.roleName != 'Manager' and role.roleName != 'Officer' }">
                    
                    <div class="form-group col  text-center pt-2"  >
                        <button type="button"
                                class="btn btn-info btn-block " role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#managerSelectForCooridnator">
                            [[#{review.submit}]]
                        </button>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this form if **classOverridden** is selected as any option then the **classOverriddenComment** should become mandetory (or  required) and must not allow the user to submit form until the comment is entered.

I am new to java script and not how to implement this functionality using js. Some sample code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by binding on change event in select(dropdown) component

Js function using jquery

```
function classOverriddenChanged() {
    let selectedValue = $("#classOverriddenId").val();
    if (selectedValue ! "") {
        $("#textAreaCommentSection").attr("required", "required");
    } 
}
```

Change in Thymleaf code (added Id in respective component)

```
<select th:field="*{classOverridden}" id="classOverriddenId"
onchange="classOverriddenChanged();" name="classOverridden">

<textarea rows="5" id="textAreaCommentSection"
  th:placeholder="#{comment}"
  th:field="*{classOverriddenComment}"
  th:value="${answeredQuestionnaire.classOverriddenComment}"
  th:text="${answeredQuestionnaire.classOverriddenComment}"
  class="form-control"></textarea>
```